# How to use aspnetdb database with an asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, aspnetdb

I have created a website using asp.net 3.5.
And now I have added member support to it using Membership API and aspnetdb database.
And I have done all testing on my local machine.
Now, what issue needs to be considered with respect to aspnetdb while uploading this site to the server. ie; how this database will be available on the server side ? 
Note : This is my first ever website.

Answer (score 4):

I was just looking for an answer to this myself.

I've found the following that might help you:
http://www.studiocoast.com.au/knowledgebase/article-6-aspnet-using-sql-server-instead-of-aspnetdbmdf.aspx

> "When developing applications in
>   ASP.NET 2.0, the default option for
>   roles and users is to use a local SQL
>   database in the App_Data directory.
>
> This works fine locally, but will
>   bring up an error when uploaded to a
>   production server.   To fix this the
>   ASP.NET membership information needs
>   to be stored in a dedicated SQL Server
>   database."
>
> "ASP.NET includes a program called
>   Aspnet_regsql.exe which you can run
>   locally to configure your database.
>   More information on the program can be
>   found here:
>
> http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx"

Answer (score 3):

Look in your C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ folder for the file InstallMembership.sql.

Thats the SQL script to create the database you need.